# What does Psalm 139:15 "..in the lowest part of the earth.." mean?

Tags: psalms, creation

The Psalmist says that our frame were made in secret in the **LOWEST PART OF THE EARTH**. What dies this refer to? What is the real meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Note the comments of Ellicott about Ps 139:15 -

> In the lowest parts of the earth.—This figurative allusion to the womb
> is intended no doubt to heighten the feeling of mystery attaching to
> birth. There may also be a covert allusion to the creation from dust
> as Ecclesiasticus 40:1, “From the day that they go out of their
> mother’s womb, till the day that they return to the mother of all
> things.” This allusion falls in with the view which meets us in other
> parts of the Old Testament, that the creation of Adam is repeated at
> every birth (Job 33:6, and see above, Psalm 139:13).
>
> Others, since the expression “lowest places of the earth” is used of
> the unseen world (Psalm 63:9; comp. Psalm 86:13), see here a
> confirmation of the view that the state before birth and after death
> are in this poem regarded as the dark void of night, with all the
> recesses of which, however, God is acquainted. (Comp. the expressions
> “Womb of Sheôl,” “Belly of hell,” Jonah 2:2; Ecclesiasticus 51:5.)

Benson is similar:

> In the womb; termed, in the next clause, in the lowest parts of the
> earth, in a place as remote from human eyes as the lowest parts of the
> earth are. He seems to allude to plants and flowers, the roots and
> first rudiments of which are formed under ground. And curiously
> wrought — Exquisitely composed of bones, muscles, sinews, arteries,
> veins, nerves, and other parts, all framed with such wonderful skill,
> that even heathen, upon the contemplation of the human body in all its
> parts, and observing how admirably they were formed for beauty and
> use, have broken forth into admiration and adoration of the Creator.

Thus, it appears that, the "depths of the earth" is a metaphor for the unseen world inside the womb.

Answer (score 1):

Womb is mentioned earlier in vs 13, there was no need to make a metaphor. Is it possible that our souls are made in the heart of the earth? “There is a physical body and a spiritual body…” and as the dead body returns to the dust, the unsaved soul goes to the pit. Every other time the word “lowest parts H8482” is used in Psalms alone it is a reference to the pit. A large majority of the time elsewhere in the Old Testament, especially Ezekiel, there’s no question as to its meaning.
There is no (other) instance of this word used for “womb” but this one time, this one verse, we attach the meaning “womb.”
I don’t buy it.
Edit: I’m not sure what this would mean other than the pit had an initial purpose that didn’t have to do with punishment or detainment. “Prepared for the devil and his angels” would simply mean “to be made ready for” like setting a table. The table was already there, it can serve more than one purpose. We know that this “heart of the earth” was partitioned for those believers who died before the Messiah came as a place where they are comforted.
Regardless, this merits investigation. The “womb” explanation seems like a meaning attached contrary to the word’s clear usage because the expositors of the past didn’t know what else to do with it. It doesn’t track with H8482‘s usage. It always means “the lowest parts” (of) (the next word). In this case that word is “eres H776” clearly meaning earth.
2nd Edit: Matt 25:41 is also most likely referring to the lake of fire which is separate from the pit. The pit is in the heart of the earth, whereas the lake of fire is also referred to as “outer darkness.” Geometrically, these two places couldn’t be more opposite. Matt 25 seems to be descriptive of the Great White Throne judgement (vs 31 and 32) and the punishment for those on the left side is the lake of fire, not the center of the earth. At this point, the first heaven and earth have passed away, and hell is cast into the lake of fire.
Let’s say however, the “everlasting” punishment is hell (even though hell has an end with the earth itself) “prepared” is G2090 in the following manner: prepare (29x), make ready (10x), provide (1x) which still fits in the analogy of setting a table. On second look, however, this verse is not talking about the origin or purpose of hell.